# How to insert new lines in Jupyter notebook by code

Tags: python, sed, jupyter-notebook

I have a notebook template, and I'm going to fill it on demand.

Lets say i have to read n pandas dataframes

The notebook template looks something like:

```
#df_id#
#df_path#
```

And by the time I'm creating it I want to get something like

```
#[input_data_id: 1]
df1 = pd.read_csv('path1')

#df_id#
#paths#
```

Like copying the tags, filling them with each new parameter and repeating

The problem is that I can't see how to insert a new line by code in a jupyter notebook

I've tried different approaches to avoid that, at this moment this is the one I'm using it:

```
for id_path in input_list:
    id_aux = id_path[0]
    path_aux = id_path[1]
    os.system("""sed -i "s|#paths#|'{0}', #paths#|" {1} """.format(path_aux,
                      file_path))
    os.system("""sed -i "s|#input_ids#|{0}, #input_ids#|" {1}""".format(id_aux,
                      file_path))
```

This results in something like this:

```
paths = [
    'path1','path2','path3'
]
```

And I can loop over it and read the dfs in another array, so in the end I can deal with it, but I would like it to looks better than now, and to get that I would need to insert new lines into the jupyter notebook cell.

I have been working on it for a few days and nothing works, I'm trying to make it easy, starting by doing my array looks from this

```
paths = [
    'path1','path2','path3'
]
```

to this:

```
paths = [
    'path1',
    'path2',
    'path3',
]
```

And the code is something like this

```
os.system("""sed -i "s|#paths#|'{0}',\n","    #paths#|" {1} """.format(path_aux_mod,file_path))
```

But it does not work. At this time I don't have any idea about how to deal it, because its not only the sed command (which i've been reading about and im not so confident about insert newlines, but also the jupyter notebook cell format which makes the cells looks like this:

This python code

```
paths = [
    'path1',
    'path2',
    'path3
]
```

In the .ipynb file

```
"paths = [\n",
"    'path1',\n",
"    'path2',\n",
"    'path3'\n",
"]\n",
```

I'm not sure if I'm even able to 'change' the cell format working with a tag that's inside the cell.

Comment: Before trying to generate the notebook from a template, have you considered keeping the notebook static and making it read all the specific content (ids, paths...) from a generated datafile delivered alongside the notebook ?

Comment: Well if you do have to generate the notebook, first, for efficiency, I'd suggest to avoid firing system commands within a loop, this brings some serious overhead. IMO it would be much better to preformat all values for a given placeholder then replace it in one call. Then, as jupyter notebooks use the json format, I'd advice against using sed (even if I love sed !) which is not suited to this kind of structured data. As you are already using python, its json library is a natural choice, otherwise [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is another powerful tool based on functional programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as long as you said, I changed the entire logic. Instead of using sed and trying to replace some tags, what I do right now is to read the .ipynb using python's json package, and because the "template" is static, I mean, the sentences to read the inputs are always in the same cell, etc. I can access to the key 'cells' with json and append the new sentences as they work as a list.

It has resulted in a much more efficient and clear solution. Thank you all.